Hamburger menu working locally but not when deployed on heroku
I am new to react I build a frontend using react and backend server is Flask. I build a cropper website for a particular type of pdf with fix coordinates. the issue is when I tested my website locally it was working totally fine. the hamburger menu was also working but now when I have deployed it on Heroku all things are working fine except the hamburger menu when the screen is small the hamburger menu appears but on clicking it nothing is happening. For CSS I am using bootstrap.

Not sure if my found may be the road to real answer.
But I found that your link told that:
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
So I tried to copy your html code to my local, then add bootstrap's necessary JS. Here it run.
Hope this test can help you something.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
